# 'for loop' repeating the first row of a table

Tags: apex, class

I have a table and I am using a for loop to get the values of the rows but this loop is duplicating the first row, I must be a easy fix but I already tried all I know. I will appreciate your help.Bellow is the code for the button I already try (i=1) that does not gives me the first row values.

```
public void doClone()
{
    SOStoupload = new List<SO_Detail__c>();
    List<String> lista= new  List<String>();
    for (relatedObjects relatedObject : objectChildren)
    {
        for (relatedObjectRow row : relatedObject.objectRows) 
        {
            if (row.selected)
            {
                // System.debug('These are the rows= '+row); debug returns the correct number of rows 
                lista.add(row.toString());
                //here for loop to get values
                for (Integer i=0;i<lista.size();i++)
                {
                    String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
                    inputvalues = lista[i].split(',');
                    System.debug('These are the values= '+'value1= '+inputvalues[0]  +' value2= '+inputvalues[1] + 'value3= '+inputvalues[2].substring(17,32));
                    // SO_Detail__c detail = new SO_Detail__c(
                    //  Outbound_Sales_Order__c = 'a0if0000000TOQp',
                    //  NRProducts__c =inputvalues[2].substring(17,32),
                    //  Qty__c = 1);
                    //SOStoupload.add(detail);
                }
                // insert SOStoupload;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `for (Integer i=0-1;i<lista.size();i++)` to `for(String item : lista)` and `inputvalues = lista[i].split(',')` to `inputvalues = item.split(',')`?

Comment: I just tried your solution but it is still repeating the first row, any ideas?

Comment: You add to lista across all "relatedObject" and all "row" and for every "row" selected you add the current lista content (that is growing all the time) to SOStoupload? Having the lista declaration inside the top of the first loop and the loop over lista just inside the bottom of the first loop would seem a more likely to work but its not clear to me what exactly you are trying to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you refactor your code like this:

```
public void doClone()
{
    SOStoupload = new List<SO_Detail__c>();
    List<String> lista= new  List<String>();
    for (relatedObjects relatedObject : objectChildren)
    {
        for (relatedObjectRow row : relatedObject.objectRows) 
        {
            if (row.selected)
            {
                // System.debug('These are the rows= '+row); debug returns the correct number of rows 
                lista.add(row.toString());
            } 
        }
        //here for loop to get values
        for (String str : lista)
        {
             String[] inputvalues = str.split(',');
             System.debug('These are the values= '+'value1= '+inputvalues[0]  +' value2= '+inputvalues[1] + 'value3= '+inputvalues[2].substring(17,32));
        }
    }
}
```

In your code line: `lista.add(row.toString());` is 0 at first run of for loop them it is 1 and process inputs. After that it has size 2 and process input at index 0 which is already processed and then index 1 and further processed 0 and 1 index which is already processed and so on. 
This will repeat all previous iterations except the last one.

Also verify that `inputValues` has list of size 3 to make safe from `index out of bound exception.`

Comment: Regal, thank you so much! you made my day. I really appreciate it!